# Passar parâmetros em uma aplicação VB6

Tags: visual-basic-6, parâmetros

Como faço para passar parâmetros em VB6?

```vb
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim cnpj As String
    cnpj = "tal"

    Dim chaveCliente As String
    chaveCliente = "tal"

    Dim chaveAcesso As String
    chaveAcesso = "tal"

    Dim status As String
    status = ""

    Dim protocolo As String
    protocolo = ""

    Dim motivoRejeicao As String
    motivoRejeicao = ""

    Dim objFuncao As Funcao

    Set objFuncao = New Funcao

    objFuncao.Consultar(ByVal cnpj As String)
```

Sendo que a `Funcao` foi adicionada como referencia de uma COM criada em .NET.
Está dando erro de sintaxe, mas em todos lugares que procurei a sintaxe de envio de parâmetros é aquela que esta no código.

Tem alguma outra alternativa ou eu estou fazendo errado?

Comment: O problema está nessa linha?
objFuncao.Consultar(ByVal cnpj As String)

Provavelmente você deveria chamar apenas o cnpj com parâmetro assim: objFuncao.Consultar(cnpj)

Comment: Qual o erro que está dando? Tente explanar um pouco mais acerca da sua dúvida.

Comment: Unica frase que o VB6 retorna é que tem erro de sintaxe. Eu estou querendo enviar todas as variáveis como parâmetro para a função que está na DLL criada em .NET, que ficaria mais ou menos assim: objFuncao.Consultar(cnpj, chaveCliente, chaveAcesso), mas com ByVal e escrevendo com cnpj As String, sempre da erro de sintaxe

Comment: Parece que você está confundindo alguma coisa, só se usa (ByVal cnpj as String) na definição de um método e não na sua chamada.

Comment: Entendi, na passagem de parâmetros só se passa as variáveis mesmo. Agora estou com outra dúvida, em C# eu passo umas variáveis do tipo out String vazias junto com o método e ele me retorna as variáveis preenchidas, como eu faço isso em vb6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro de sintaxe está nessa linha:

```
objFuncao.Consultar(ByVal cnpj As String)
```

O correto seria simplesmente:

```
objFuncao.Consultar(cnpj)
```

Esse formato se usa na assinatura da função:

```
ByVal [nome variável] As [Tipo Variável]
ByRef [nome variável] As [Tipo Variável]
```

Sendo que `ByVal`é o padrão e pode ser omitido.

Exemplo:

```
Private Function Soma(ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer)
    Soma = x + y
End Function

[..]
    z = Soma(1, 2)
```

Leitura recomendada: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ddck1z30.aspx